# How to disable directory listing in minihttpd?

Tags: web-services

Change /etc/apache2/apache2.conf can disable directory listing in apache.
So is it possible to disable directory listing in minihttpd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the mini_httpd.c to return 403 Forbid instead of return the file list.

For example, add the following code in function do_dir:

```
send_error( 403, "Forbidden", "", "Directory is protected." );
```